# Problems with android RelativeLayout and setBackGroundColor

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with my Android application.
My Android application's task is as follows: there is an activity where a table exists.
[The image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neP7D.png)

When I try to set the background of my button programatticaly I faced with problem that the textView (which represents the number of cell) disappears.

[This problem on the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK7jv.png)
As you can see the numbers of the cells disappeared.

Layout that represents each cell:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button0"
                style="@style/button_in_table_attributes"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView0"
                style="@style/number_of_cell"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/button0"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/button0"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

My styles

```
<style name="button_in_table_attributes">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/zero</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
</style>
<style name="number_of_cell">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">"@color/black"</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">5dp</item>
</style>
```

I set the color of button here

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String union = unionList.get(position);
    String[] numberTokens = union.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split("[,\\s]+");

    int[] unionArray = new int[numberTokens.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberTokens.length; i++) {
        unionArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberTokens[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < unionArray.length; i++) {
        if (unionArray[i] >= 0 && unionArray[i] < buttonIds.length) {
            Button button = holder.buttonViews[i];
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the other remaining classes and details of unionList please ?